# Post Data with Ajax works in Windows not in Apple. Any idea?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api, cross-browser

On a page I am calling an ASP.NET Web API action as follows:

```
$.post('/api/mail/send/', { '': $('form #mail').val() }).done(function () { 
  $('form #send').addClass('sent').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); 
  $('form #mail').val('') 
});
```

On any browser in Windows the code inside the done function runs well.

On an Apple that code does not run at all in any browser.

**In both cases the action is always called and the email is sent.**

The Web API action is as follows:

```
[Route("api/mail/send"), HttpPost]
public void Send([FromBody]String email) {
}
```

I have no idea what might be wrong here.

Does anyone has a clue?

Comment: Which browsers and what versions did you try for each OS?

Comment: Tip: This `.attr('disabled', 'disabled');` should be `.prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: I notice that I had an absolute path on AJAX call and not relative ... That simply created the problems in Apple systems.